# Talend backend code - in python?

Tags: python, talend

Is there a way to get the talend back end code in Python?
As known to all that the backend is in Java...
Big Data is java spark-- is there any way to generate it in Python Spark?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the talend back end code in Python?

Nope.

Talend Studio / ETL is a proprietary software created by the team of Talend. They have created a code generator in Java for Java. They heavily use the Java Eclipse version. They have build millions of line of code into Java libraries. There are no plans to do the same in Python just for the fun of it.

Instead, this really shouldn't bother at all. Even if it was written in VBA (buuaaah) the end user would care unless he would try to extend the funcionality.

> is there any way to generate it in Python Spark?

And nope again. No Python possible. Also, Spark needs to be adapted into the code generator. Again, why should Talend do that if they have a powerful tool already and the use case for Spark is different?